# What is the significance of having Prime Ideal Theorem in models for failure of Axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Prime Ideal Theorem says:

> **PIT:** Every ideal on a Boolean algebra can be extended to a prime ideal.

It follows from Axiom of Choice but is weaker than it.

In many cases I saw that people check for having $\sf PIT$ in models for $\sf \neg AC$.

> Why? What is the significance of having Prime Ideal Theorem in the absence of $\sf AC$? What sort of choice related set theoretic tools are available merely by $\sf PIT$?

Comment: This question is on-topic here at MO.  @Asaf, why not just answer it?

Comment: @Joel: I actually find it too broad. It's like asking what sort of tools are available to us assuming the axiom of choice. Great many of them. And by opening up a book about the axiom of choice (specifically "Consequences of the Axiom of Choice", but also "The Axiom of Choice" by Herrlich, and Jech "The Axiom of Choice" could be good choices) will probably end up giving more information than I could possibly deliver on this website.

Comment: Well, it seems more like asking what are the issues about having only PIT instead of AC. I think that many mathematicians would appreciate a well-thought-out summary answer to that.

Comment: I'm not sure the question would be such a duplicate. OP does not say she is looking for a bunch of consequences, but for the scope of set-theoretic tools made available under this weaker form of choice. One such is the ultrafilter lemma (one can choose an ultrafilter extending any proper filter), which is quite a powerful tool. Such a tool is used for example to construct ultraproducts, in the compactness theorem, and so on. I think a more creative answer might be possible, here at MO.

Answer (score 0):

*This is kind of tangential to the OP, but it's too long for a comment.*

First, let me point out that the general question of which choice principles imply which others is interesting from a purely technical standpoint. The proof techniques required to show that one form of choice does not imply another are often quite subtle.

This doesn't address your question, though, which I see as having two parts:

> (1) What tools does PIT provide us?

which is your main question, but also

> (2) Why are we interested in models of ZF+PIT+$\neg$AC?

For (1), PIT has powerful applications in logic and point-set topology, in the form of various **compactness** results: e.g., the compactness theorem for first-order logic in arbitrary languages, and the Hahn-Banach theorem in topology. Of course, it doesn't get us everything - Tychonoff's theorem, for example, is equivalent to full AC - but it gets us a fair amount.

For (2), even if what we really care about is ZFC, we often find that questions about the universe are closely tied to properties of *inner models* - that is, transitive proper classes containing all the ordinals which are models of ZF. These include, for example, $L(\mathbb{R})$, the smallest inner model containing every real. In many cases of interest, AC fails in inner models: for example, in the presence of large cardinals, $L(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the *axiom of determinacy*, a very different sort of animal. It suddenly becomes important to know what choice principles might hold in such inner models, and this is tied up with understanding what choice principles imply what other choice principles. For the specific case of PIT, this is admittedly purely speculative on my part - I don't know how important this specific form of choice is in the context of inner models; for example, the axiom of determinacy destroys it, so it tends not to hold in $L(\mathbb{R})$ - but I do find it a good heuristic argument for caring about separations of choice principles in general.

Comment: $\sf BPI$ is equivalent to Tychonoff's theorem for Hausdorff spaces. The Hahn-Banach theorem is strictly weaker. Both are non-set theoretical though. It should be noted that while $\sf BPI$ supplies us with free ultrafilters, assuming $\sf BPI$ together with Los theorem implies choice, so ultraproducts may still behave quirky without choice.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to imply that BPI was equivalent to Hahn-Banach.